# VideoJS with Meteor 0.8 Blaze

Tags: meteor, video.js

Previously I used the rendered function to initialize videoJS when the Video Changed.

Now in Meteor 0.8. the rendered is only fired once, when the template was created.

The problem is: the template is used in each page, I navigate through, so it is never rerendered and just changed the attributes.

Is there any way to get VideoJS working in Meteor 0.8?

- Something like rendered function for template fields that fires always
- or a way to force the complete template to rerender
- or a way to run a callback when the content of a helper is inserted.

Comment: If the _id changes when the video changes then you can use an {{#each}} block to display it will not reuse the DOM element which means a `render` event will occur.  Discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/meteor-talk/$23each$20video%7Csort:date/meteor-talk/bheOi3EmPeE/VsI_8sD0zAEJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to force the behaviour of Meteor < 0.8:

Make 2 Handlers:

```
UI.registerHelper "handler1", (data) ->
    Session.set("loading", true);

UI.registerHelper "handler2", (data) ->
    if Session.get("loading")
        Session.set("loading", false);
        return true
    else
        return false
```

Define 2 Template:

```
<template name="videoPlayer">
    {{handler1 seed="videourl"}}
    {{#if handler2}}
        Loading Player...
    {{else}}
        {{> videoPlayerInternal}}
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="videoPlayerInternal">
    <!-- VideoJS-Player-Code -->
</template>
```

Now, I can hook the rendered method of `videoPlayerInternal` and this works like meteor < 0.8.

This works because:

In Initialization, only handler1 is called. This sets the variable "loading" to true.

After that I have a if-then-else that in the initial state shows a loading text. Because the condition is calculated by a helper that has a side effect (setting the session variable loading to false) it will be called immediatly after that.

So If I load another exactly same page with another video url, it needs to re run the handler1, wich sets the session variable to true again, that deletes the template from the dom and reinserts that. The rendered is called again and voila it works ;-)

Oh... and of course, the rendered method:

```
Template.videoPlayerInternal.rendered = ->
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "/video-js.swf"

    # Delete old players and reset.
    if videojs.players.videoJsPlayer
        videojs.players.videoJsPlayer.dispose()


    # Initialize the player
    $vid_obj = _V_ "videoJsPlayer", {}, ()->
        console.log "video is ready.";
        return true
```